# proxy tunneling with c

Tags: c, http, networking, proxy, proxytunnel

I am working on a small project (C programming) to tunnel through a proxy and when I try to do it I get a error:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/2.7.STABLE9
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 22:20:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html 
Content-Length: 1456
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0
X-Cache: MISS from xt03
Via: 1.0 xt03:80 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Connection: close
```

The data I am sending to the proxy server is:

```
 char msg[] = "CONNECT example.com:80 HTTP/1.0 <CR><LF> HOST example.com:80 <CR><LF> \n";
```

Any help would be great!

------ UPDATE ------

I have tried the methods you guys suggested and I am still getting an error. I will post my entire set of code and see if it is something in the socket causing it to send the wrong information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define maxlen 2048

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int mysocket;
int len;
char buffer[2000];
char msg[] = "CONNECT example.org:80 HTTP/1.0 \r\n HOST example.org:80 \r\n\r\n";


mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in dest;

memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));

dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("125.39.66.150");
dest.sin_port = htons(80);

connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

send(mysocket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
len = recv(mysocket, buffer, maxlen, 0);

buffer[len] = '\0';

printf("%s \n", buffer);
close(mysocket);
return 0;
```

}

----- UPDATE ------

New error:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/2.7.STABLE5
Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2013 22:40:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1158
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0
X-Cache: MISS from DXT-BJ-219
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from DXT-BJ-219:80
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css"><!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-    serif}PRE{font-family:sans-serif}--></STYLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
<P> 
While trying to process the request:
<PRE>
CONNECT example.com:80 HTTP/1.1


</PRE>
<P>
The following error was encountered:
<UL>
<LI>
<STRONG>
Invalid Request
</STRONG>
</UL>

<P>
Some aspect of the HTTP Request is invalid.  Possible problems:
<UL>
<LI>Missing or unknown request method
<LI>Missing URL
<LI>Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0)
<LI>Request is too large
<LI>Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests
<LI>Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed
</UL>
<P>Your cache administrator is <A HREF="mailto:noc_admin@163.com">noc_admin@163.com</A>. 

<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<ADDRESS>
by DXT-BJ-219
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this: [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

10.4.1 **400 Bad Request**

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

When you are passing:

```
char msg[] = "CONNECT example.com:80 HTTP/1.0 <CR><LF> HOST example.com:80 <CR><LF> \n";
```

Then perhaps the `<CR>` and `<LF>` parts are sent as it is as strings, instead of the ASCII 0xA and 0xD, which represent the control characters you intend to send.
The simplest fix would be using C equivalents: `\r` for `<CR>` and `\n` for `<LF>`:

```
char msg[] = "CONNECT example.com:80 HTTP/1.0 \r\n HOST example.com:80 \r\n\r\n";
```

If you intend to expand the use of the `msg[]` array to contain many more requests you might have to write a wrapper function to translate the CR,LF and other control strings in the `msg[]` into appropriate C char equivalents to form proper message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Blank line is required at the end of the header: \r\n\r\n.

Comment: How is this any different to the answer that I provided?

Comment: Reliable References to the error code and descriptive. Addressing the vagueness inherent in the question about the future usage of msg[].

Answer (score 3):

“Bad request” meant that the request you sent to the server was malformed and couldn't be understood. I think the reason for this is that you are sending the **8** characters `<CR><LF>` (as in, '<', 'C', 'R' etc.) rather than the 2 characters that they should represent, i.e. `\r\n`.

Try

```
char msg[] = "CONNECT example.com:80 HTTP/1.0\r\nHOST example:80\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: I tried the suggested above but I still am getting the same error. I posted the rest of my code on the main section. Maybe it has something to do with the socket.

Comment: @user1626342: Don't put any spaces around the `\r\n`. I have a feeling that each new line must *not* start with a space.

Comment: I tried it without spaces and got the exact same error. I attached the rest of my code up above? Is there something else I am doing wrong? Thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: @user1626342: Try using just the CONNECT line, e.g. `"CONNECT example.com:80 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\b"`. Maybe it doesn't like the `HOST` command in the request.

Comment: When I tried the new way I got a different type of error. It more or less produced a html page that stated an error. I posted it on the main section as a update.

Comment: When I used the "GET" command it pulled up all the data (html) from the page and worked correctly. However I am pretty sure I need to use the connect command since that is what is mentioned all over the web.

Comment: Fixed it by changing to an https server. Apparently the connect function does not work well with only http proxys.